# How to get the key from a know value using dictionary comprehension

Tags: key, python-3.6, dictionary-comprehension

Suppose I have a variable `state = "MD"` which can be found in a dictionary:

```
stateabb = {'Alabama': 'AL','Alaska': 'AK','Arizona': 'AZ','Arkansas': 'AR','California': 'CA','Colorado': 'CO','Connecticut': 'CT','Delaware': 'DE','DistrictOfColumbia': 'DC','Florida': 'FL',
'Georgia': 'GA','Hawaii': 'HI','Idaho': 'ID','Illinois': 'IL','Indiana': 'IN','Iowa': 'IA','Kansas': 'KS','Kentucky': 'KY','Louisiana': 'LA','Maine': 'ME','Maryland': 'MD',
'Massachusetts': 'MA','Michigan': 'MI','Minnesota': 'MN','Mississippi': 'MS','Missouri': 'MO','Montana': 'MT','Nebraska': 'NE','Nevada': 'NV','NewHampshire': 'NH',
'NewJersey': 'NJ','NewMexico': 'NM','NewYork': 'NY','NorthCarolina': 'NC','NorthDakota': 'ND','Ohio': 'OH','Oklahoma': 'OK','Oregon': 'OR','Pennsylvania': 'PA',
'RhodeIsland': 'RI','SouthCarolina': 'SC','SouthDakota': 'SD','Tennessee': 'TN','Texas': 'TX','Utah': 'UT','Vermont': 'VT','Virginia': 'VA','Washington': 'WA',
'WestVirginia': 'WV','Wisconsin': 'WI','Wyoming': 'WY'}
```

I want to have a quick function that uses dictionary comprehension to get the matching `key['stateName']` based on the `value['state']` and assign it to an empty variable:

```
stateName = ""
def long_name(stAbbrev):
    stateName = [key: key for v[stAbbrev]in stateabb.items()]
    return stateName
stateName = long_name(state)
```

Note: this is not quite right; what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to your own question is correct, but not optimal. Every time you want to get a state name by its abbreviation, you iterate over  state/abbr couples until you find the expected abbreviation (the time complexity is O(n) where n is the number of states). Since you have one and only one abbreviation by state, it is easy to reverse the dictionary:

```
>>> stateabb = {'Alabama': 'AL','Alaska': 'AK','Arizona': 'AZ','Arkansas': 'AR','California': 'CA','Colorado': 'CO','Connecticut': 'CT','Delaware': 'DE','DistrictOfColumbia': 'DC','Florida': 'FL', 'Georgia': 'GA','Hawaii': 'HI','Idaho': 'ID','Illinois': 'IL','Indiana': 'IN','Iowa': 'IA','Kansas': 'KS','Kentucky': 'KY','Louisiana': 'LA','Maine': 'ME','Maryland': 'MD', 'Massachusetts': 'MA','Michigan': 'MI','Minnesota': 'MN','Mississippi': 'MS','Missouri': 'MO','Montana': 'MT','Nebraska': 'NE','Nevada': 'NV','NewHampshire': 'NH', 'NewJersey': 'NJ','NewMexico': 'NM','NewYork': 'NY','NorthCarolina': 'NC','NorthDakota': 'ND','Ohio': 'OH','Oklahoma': 'OK','Oregon': 'OR','Pennsylvania': 'PA', 'RhodeIsland': 'RI','SouthCarolina': 'SC','SouthDakota': 'SD','Tennessee': 'TN','Texas': 'TX','Utah': 'UT','Vermont': 'VT','Virginia': 'VA','Washington': 'WA', 'WestVirginia': 'WV','Wisconsin': 'WI','Wyoming': 'WY'}
>>> state_name_by_abb = {v: k for k, v in stateabb.items()}
>>> state_name_by_abb
{'AL': 'Alabama', 'AK': 'Alaska', 'AZ': 'Arizona', 'AR': 'Arkansas', 'CA': 'California', 'CO': 'Colorado', 'CT': 'Connecticut', 'DE': 'Delaware', 'DC': 'DistrictOfColumbia', 'FL': 'Florida', 'GA': 'Georgia', 'HI': 'Hawaii', 'ID': 'Idaho', 'IL': 'Illinois', 'IN': 'Indiana', 'IA': 'Iowa', 'KS': 'Kansas', 'KY': 'Kentucky', 'LA': 'Louisiana', 'ME': 'Maine', 'MD': 'Maryland', 'MA': 'Massachusetts', 'MI': 'Michigan', 'MN': 'Minnesota', 'MS': 'Mississippi', 'MO': 'Missouri', 'MT': 'Montana', 'NE': 'Nebraska', 'NV': 'Nevada', 'NH': 'NewHampshire', 'NJ': 'NewJersey', 'NM': 'NewMexico', 'NY': 'NewYork', 'NC': 'NorthCarolina', 'ND': 'NorthDakota', 'OH': 'Ohio', 'OK': 'Oklahoma', 'OR': 'Oregon', 'PA': 'Pennsylvania', 'RI': 'RhodeIsland', 'SC': 'SouthCarolina', 'SD': 'SouthDakota', 'TN': 'Tennessee', 'TX': 'Texas', 'UT': 'Utah', 'VT': 'Vermont', 'VA': 'Virginia', 'WA': 'Washington', 'WV': 'WestVirginia', 'WI': 'Wisconsin', 'WY': 'Wyoming'}
```

Then find any state name by its abbreviation in amortized O(1) time:

```
>>> state_name_by_abb["HI"]
'Hawaii'
```

Aside from time complexity consideration, this method seems (to me) easier to understand.

Comment: That was a good improvement; reversing the order of the v and k in the dictionary worked nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the answer was simple. I just to make a slight adjustment and add an `if` statement:

```
def long_name(stAbbrev):
stateName = [k for k, v in stateabb.items() if v == stAbbrev]
return stateName
```